# What is difference between :o and :e in vim when using these command to load a file into the buffer?

Tags: vim, vi

I was watching an online tutorial  by tutsplus , during one of the lessons, the teacher started to move between buffers using :bn :bn :b#, but he forget to mention how to load files into the buffer before talking about navigating between the buffers, I searched and find that using:e filename or :o filename would load a file into the buffer.

So, what is the difference , I can't understand the document explanation provide within vim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that you shouldn't use `:o`, which is a useless artefact of vi compatibility, and use `:e` (or one of its alternative) instead.

From `:help :o`:

```
Vim does not support open mode, since it's not really useful.  For those
situations where ":open" would start open mode Vim will leave Ex mode, which
allows executing the same commands, but updates the whole screen instead of
only one line.
```

Just… forget that command even exists.

FWIW, even [the vi specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) is pretty vague about what open mode is and does.